# WARNING: Node v10.8.0 is not tested against Ember CLI on your platform

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember.js-3

I successfully installed Node 10.8.0, npm 6.3.0 and ember-cli 3.3.0 on my mac:

```
$ ember -v
ember-cli: 3.3.0
node: 10.8.0
os: darwin x64

$ npm -v
6.3.0
```

However, when I run

```
ember serve
```

on the ember demo project (super-rentals), I still get this error - even though the link says that the combination of ember & node is fine:

> WARNING: Node v10.8.0 is not tested against Ember CLI on your
>   platform. We recommend that you use the most-recent "Active LTS"
>   version of Node.js. See https://git.io/v7S5n for details.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: It is prolly fine. It's just saying that Ember hasn't been tested with that version of Node on your OS, Darwin. You might run into unexpected bugs though.

Comment: It's also just a warning. Those can be ignored in many cases. But you may need to be aware of bugs that are related to the warnings